# Issue regarding delete operation in python flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my app.py code

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= "sqlite:///book.db"

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_track_MODIFICATIONS']= False

with app.app_context():

    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Book(db.Model):

    Sno = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)

    Book_name = db.Column(db.String(300),nullable = False)

    Category = db.Column(db.String(300),nullable = False)

    Author = db.Column(db.String(300),nullable = False)

    Date_issued = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:

        return f"{self.Book_name}-{self.Author}"

    

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])

def hello_world(): #different pages

    if request.method=='POST':

         title=(request.form['title'])

         cat=(request.form['category'])

         author=(request.form['author'])

         book=Book(Book_name=title,Author=author,Category=cat)

         db.session.add(book)

         db.session.commit()

    allBook= Book.query.all()

    

    return render_template('index.html', allBook=allBook)

    #return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/show')

def products():

     allBook= Book.query.all()

     print(allBook)

     return 'Here are some amazing products!'

@app.route('/update')

def update():

     allBook= Book.query.all()

     print(allBook)

     return 'Here are some amazing products!'

@app.route('/delete/<int:Sno>')

def delete(Sno):

     book= Book.query.filter_by(Sno=Sno)

     db.session.delete(book)

     db.session.commit()

     return redirect("/")

if __name__=="__main__":

    app.run(debug=True,port=8000)
```

And this is a part of my index.html code

```
<td>{{book.Book_name}}</td>

                <td>{{book.Author}}</td>

                <td>{{book.Category}}</td>

                <td>{{book.Date_issued}}</td>

                <td><a href="/update/{{book.Sno}}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mx-1">Update</button></td>

                <td><a href="/delete/{{book.Sno}}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mx-1">Delete</button></td>
```

I am trying to make a todo list and I am not able to perform delete operation.

Even though I am clicking on the delete button still it is not deleting that record, it is remaining as it is.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a execution method on your query. With you existing code it will only produce a query, but not execute it, so you are now trying to delete a query instead of the actual db object.

Instead of this:

```
book= Book.query.filter_by(Sno=Sno)
```

Do this:

```
book= Book.query.filter_by(Sno=Sno).first()
```